# SQL Server Query Performance on MS Dynamics View

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-dynamics

I have an out of box view that is used with MS Dynamics, it runs so slow that the reporting cubes will not process.  I can do a select * from the table, however, when I filter on one of the view columns the query never completes:

This runs fast:

```
select * from inventtableexpanded
```

however this times out after an hour:

```
select * from inventtableexpanded

Where partition= 5637155555
```

There are about 600,000 records in the underlying table (inventtable), and I can not index the view as it is not a schema bound view.

edit:  when I run against the underlying table its fast, only when i run against the view and filter does it completely grind to a halt.

Comment: Please check your indexes fragmentation especially index that include [partition] column. If index fragmentation is high, rebuild. Then try it again.

Comment: Thanks, i reorganized the indexes and stats on the underlying tables and the views still run slow, especially when filtering on partition.  It looks like the ecoresproductcategoryexpanded view is causing the latency.  It appears to be a big cross join view and I have a lot of data.

Comment: Looks like the view joins ECORESPRODUCT and ECORESPRODUCTCATEGORY each with 825,000 and 88,000 rows respectively.  Looks like this is causing the latency in the view.

The problem is I can not put indexes on this view, I can not filter out joins to make the view more efficient.  Any suggestions?